# How to prevent camera from going through specific layers

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a camera controller that can move, zoom and rotate the camera. It's pretty much the exact camera controller from Cities Skyline. i.e top-down with some freedom of movement.

I am using `CheckSphere` to detect when the camera collides with wall/ground layers, and this works perfectly. However my issue is I do not know how to reset it's position to the last valid one, and to keep it there until the camera chooses a valid direction. At the moment as soon as my `CheckSphere` hits a wall, the camera is stuck and no longer responds to input.

I tried to store the last valid position, rotation and zoom and simply force this when `CheckSphere` hits something, but it's not working.

Is there some way I can can use this method with `CheckSphere` in a way that the camera won't get stuck every time it hits something it's not allowed to hit?

```
void HandleInput()
    {
        if (Physics.CheckSphere(cameraTransform.position, 7, collideWith))
        {
            newPosition = oldPosition;
            newRotation = oldRotation;
            newZoom = oldZoom;
            
            Debug.Log("Did Hit");
        }
        else
        {
            //Speed controls
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
            {
                movementSpeed = fastSpeed;
            }
            else
            {
                movementSpeed = normalSpeed;
            }

            // Adjust movement speed based on camera zoom
            movementSpeed *= (cameraTransform.localPosition.y / zoomSpeedFactor);

            Vector3 adjustedForward = transform.forward;
            adjustedForward.y = 0;

            //Movement controls
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
            {
                newPosition += (adjustedForward * movementSpeed);
            }
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
            {
                newPosition += (adjustedForward * -movementSpeed);
            }
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
            {
                newPosition += (transform.right * movementSpeed);
            }
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
            {
                newPosition += (transform.right * -movementSpeed);
            }

            //Rotation controls
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(2))
            {
                rotateStartPosition = Input.mousePosition;
            }
            if (Input.GetMouseButton(2))
            {
                rotateCurrentPosition = Input.mousePosition;

                Vector3 difference = rotateStartPosition - rotateCurrentPosition;
                rotateStartPosition = rotateCurrentPosition;

                newRotation *= Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.up * (-difference.x / 5f));
                newRotation *= Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.right * (difference.y / 5f));

                Vector3 euler = newRotation.eulerAngles;
                euler.x = ClampAngle(euler.x, verticalRotationClamp.x, verticalRotationClamp.y);
                euler.z = 0;

                newRotation.eulerAngles = euler;
            }

            //Zoom controls
            if (Input.mouseScrollDelta.y != 0 && !EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
            {
                newZoom -= Input.mouseScrollDelta.y * zoomAmount;
                newZoom.y = ClampValue(newZoom.y, zoomClamp.x, zoomClamp.y);
                newZoom.z = ClampValue(newZoom.z, -zoomClamp.y, -zoomClamp.x);
            }

            oldPosition = new Vector3(newPosition.x, newPosition.y, newPosition.z);
            oldRotation = new Quaternion(newRotation.x, newRotation.y, newRotation.z, newRotation.w);
            oldZoom = new Vector3(newZoom.x, newZoom.y, newZoom.z);

            Debug.Log("Did not Hit");
        }

        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, newPosition, Time.unscaledDeltaTime * acceleration);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, newRotation, Time.unscaledDeltaTime * acceleration);
        cameraTransform.localPosition = Vector3.Lerp(cameraTransform.localPosition, newZoom, Time.unscaledDeltaTime * acceleration);
    }
```

Comment: It looks like the imaginary collision sphere is getting embedded in a collision, and the way your code is structured, it has no way to exit the collision because you stop processing inputs. You should either test where the camera wants to be in the next frame, and if that's about to collide, resolve that. Or, resolve the collision by marching the camera forward until it is no longer colliding.